# cannot bind by-move into a pattern guard

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

How do I fix the problem of `cannot bind by-move into a pattern guard [E0008]` on `s`?

```
let res = match Some("hi".to_string()) {
    Some(s) if s.len() == 0 => 1,
    _ => 3
};
```

Is there anyway of changing it without putting the condition in the arm?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In this case, you can bind by reference:

```
let res = match Some("hi".to_string()) {
    Some(ref s) if s.len() == 0 => 1,
    _ => 3
};
```

The general problem here is that binding by move must disallow further uses of the original variable, as moving out invalidates the data. If the guard is `false`, then the original variable needs to be used to match against the later patterns, which is illegal due to the move.

For example:

```
fn f(x: Option<String>) {
    match x {
        Some(a) if { drop(a); false } => println!("impossible"),
        Some(b) => println!("whoops, {}", b),
        None => println!("none"),
    }
}
```

If `x` is `Some`, the internal `String` is moved out and deallocated when deciding if `a` arm should be taken, but that same `String` is immediately used again for the `b` arm once the `a` arm is rejected.

Comment: So basically what the compiler is saying is "Hey, I'm happy to move 'e' into the guard statement, but if the guard statement fails, there's no way I can move 'e' back. So the only way this is gonna work is if you let me borrow 'e' to check the guard statement."

Comment: What if I don't need ownership in the guard expression, but do in the body?

Comment: @Thayne apparently you need to use Rust 2018 edition with `#![feature(bind_by_move_pattern_guards)]`, wait until the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0107-pattern-guards-with-bind-by-move.md) is fully implemented, or move the guard into the match body.

Comment: RFC now is stabilized: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/63118